# Merging two variables in google apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

```
function f(column) {
    var i = 4;
}
```

I want to merge the "column" and "i" variable so I can use it as input in the spreadsheet function getRange();

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you want to use i as an offset along with column.

If so then

```
function f(column) {
    var i = 4;
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A1").offset(0, column + i, 1, 1);
}
```

would return a single cell, 4 + column to the right of A1.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, there is a pretty simple way to do that: I'm guessing if column="A" and as i=4, you want to set something into A4 cell, then do like this:

```
function f(column)
{
  var i = 4;
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(column+i).setValue("Hello World");
}
```

Here, `getRange()` is accepting input value as "A4" or a1Notation.